# Silverstripe 4 - SiteConfig module Image not working in template

Tags: image, url, silverstripe

I can't seem to get Silverstripe 4 to display images included in SiteConfig in my templates at all.I used to be able to just doe something like $SiteConfig.Logo and it would print out a automatic  tag.

CustomSiteConfig:

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataExtension;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextareaField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\HeaderField;
use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Image;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;


class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension
{

    private static $db = [

    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'Logo' => Image::class,
        'MobileLogo' => Image::class
    ];

    private static $owns = [
        'Logo',
        "MobileLogo"
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {

        $uploader = UploadField::create('Logo');
        $uploader->setFolderName('Logo');
        $uploader->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(['png','gif','jpeg','jpg']);

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', [
            HeaderField::create('hf2','Default logo'),
            $uploader
        ]);

        $uploader2 = UploadField::create('MobileLogo');
        $uploader2->setFolderName('MobileLogo');
        $uploader2->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(['png','gif','jpeg','jpg']);

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', [
            HeaderField::create('hf3','Mobile Logo'),
            $uploader2
        ]);


    }
}
```

But when I try in my template file. I get no URL

```
$SiteConfig.Logo
or
$SiteConfig.Logo().Link
etc
```

Nothing works?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- Verify that $SiteConfig is available as variable at that point in your template (Try using $SiteConfig.Title)
- Verify that the extension is actually added to SiteConfig (do you see the CMS Fields?)
- Did you add $owns later? run ?flush=1 again and re-save the SiteConfig *
- Verify that both the SiteConfig and the File is published. (Save & Publish the SiteConfig twice, then check in the file manager if the file is published) **

[*] $owns is just a directive that when SiteConfig->doPublish() is called, it will also publish all files
[**] I've seen a bug that DataObjects don't actually publish files sometimes. Saving twice might work.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Zauberfisch said, your image is probably not published. However, publishing the image after writing the owner can be tricky.

I usually through in this code

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    if ( $this->LogoID ) {
        $this->Logo()->doPublish();
    }
    if ( $this->MobileLogoID ) {
        $this-> MobileLogo()->doPublish();
    }

}
```

It's messy, I know, but it can save you a couple of hours. After saving you can remove it as the $owns hook will start to kick-in to all newly created objects.

Answer (score 0):

We can Use This one

$SiteConfig.Logo.URL